# SyntaxError: keyword argument repeated: status

Tags: python-3.x, django-models

***Modles.Py file***

```
 class PostJobs1(models.Model):
        recruiter = models.ForeignKey(Recruiter,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        jobtitle = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        vacancy = models.IntegerField()
        category = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        status = models.CharField(max_length=50)
        deadline = models.DateField()
        resume_receive = models.CharField(max_length=30)
        job_seekers_instructions = models.CharField(max_length=250)
        joblabel = models.CharField(max_length=50)
        image = models.FileField()
        jobcontext = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        job_description = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        work_place = models.CharField(max_length=70)
        job_location = models.CharField(max_length=50)
        salary = models.CharField(max_length=20)
        minsal = models.IntegerField()
        maxsal = models.IntegerField()
        saldesc = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        benefitdesc = models.CharField(max_length=70)
        academicqua = models.CharField(max_length=80)
        academic = models.CharField(max_length=90)
        prefered_institution = models.CharField(max_length=150)
        edu_desc = models.CharField(max_length=150)
        profession_deg = models.CharField(max_length=60)
        train_desc = models.CharField(max_length=150)
        experience = models.CharField(max_length=20)
        exp_desc = models.CharField(max_length=150)
        skills = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        additional_requirements = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        gender = models.CharField(max_length=20)
        minage = models.IntegerField()
        maxage = models.IntegerField()
        creation_date = models.DateField(null=True)
        status=models.CharField(max_length=20,null=True)
        def __str__(self):
            return self.jobtitle
```

***This is my views.py function.*
*while i am trying to saving the views function it's showing error. the problem is after try block. but i think it's ok. but why this problem occured i don't know actually*

***Views.py*****

```
 def post_job1(request):
        if not request.user.is_authenticated:
            return redirect('recruiter_login')
        error = ""
        if request.method == "POST":
            jt = request.POST['jobtitle']
            vac = request.POST['vacancy']
            cat = request.POST['category']
            empstat = request.POST['emstatus']
            dl = request.POST['deadline']
            resume = request.POST['resumereceive']
            jis = request.POST['jobseekersinstruction']
            jl = request.POST['joblabel']
            i = request.FILES['image']
            jc = request.POST['jobcontext']
            desc = request.POST['jobresponsibility']
            wp = request.POST['workplace']
            loc = request.POST['joblocation']
            sal = request.POST['salary']
            minsal = request.POST['minsal']
            maxsal = request.POST['maxsal']
            sald = request.POST['saldesc']
            bdesc = request.POST['benefitdesc']
            aq = request.POST['academicqualificaton']
            d = request.POST['degree']
            pei = request.POST['pei']
            ed = request.POST['edudesc']
            pd = request.POST['pd']
            td = request.POST['traindesc']
            exp = request.POST['exp']
            expd = request.POST['expdesc']
            skills = request.POST['skills']
            ar = request.POST['ar']
            gender = request.POST['gender']
            minage = request.POST['minage']
            maxage = request.POST['maxage']
            user = request.user
            recruiter = Recruiter.objects.get(user=user)
            try:
                PostJobs1.objects.create(recruiter=recruiter,jobtitle=jt,vacancy=vac,category= cat,status= empstat, deadline=dl,resume_receive= resume,job_seekers_instructions= jis,joblabel=jl,image=i,jobcontext= jc,job_description=desc,work_place=wp,job_location=loc,salary=sal, minsal=minsal,maxsal=maxsal,saldesc=sald,benefitdesc= bdesc,academicqua=aq,academic=d,prefered_institution= pei,edu_desc=ed,profession_deg=pd,train_desc=td,experience=exp,exp_desc=expd,skills=skills,additional_requirements=ar,gender=gender,minage=minage,maxage=maxage,creation_date=date.today(),status="pending")
            error = "No"
        except:
            error = "Yes"
        d={'error':error}
    return render(request,'RecruiterFeatures/job_post1.html')
```

---

- while i am saving views.py file it's showing a error. "SyntaxError: keyword argument repeated: status"
  -if i remove the code from my django app it's work properly. Please tell me the solution

Answer (score 0):

In your `PostJobs1` model, field `status` defined two times

```
class PostJobs1(models.Model):
        ...
        status = models.CharField(max_length=50)
        ...
        status=models.CharField(max_length=20,null=True)
```

Remove one of it.

Comment: Glad to hear, consider accepting the answer, if it was useful @Md.KawserAhmed